# log4j issue in selenium java project

Tags: java, selenium, log4j

-Dlog4j.debug=true

How to make the above feature available for all classes?

I can only run it in 1 class by manually putting it in debug configuration but when I go to run another class it doesn't work.

I want the following description available in console for all test classes:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05.
log4j: Using URL 
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, console, file  ].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %F %-5p [%t] %c{2} %L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "console".
log4j: Parsed "console" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "file".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "file".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "file".
log4j: Setting property [append] to [false].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [application.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [10mb ].
log4j: setFile called: application.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "file" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

Comment: Can you please extend your question and elaborte it? Please add more details. Right now I do not understand your question.

Comment: I am sorry new to this; I added the message I am getting from the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How log4j is configured?
To configure log4j we have to decide which appender to implement. Accordingly, parameters of appender will be set.

We will use DEBUG level and RollingFileAppender
We will do two configurations or logs,
First: root logger, that will write all system generated logs in file name i.e. Selenium.logs
Second: Will write the information generated by manual commands in code into the file name- Manual.logs
Layout will be PatternLayout

## Root logger

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\ProjectXXX\\src\\Selenium.logs
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c<strong>{1}</strong>:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
```

## Application Logs

```
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=D:\\ ProjectXXX\\src\\Manual.logs
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

In the above code, we have configured log4j to log in two different files named as Selenium.log and Manual.log.

file and dest1 are the two identifiers.
"File" is used to give file name in which logs will be saved
"maxFileSize" is used to configure the maximum size of the log file. When file reaches this size, a new file will be created with the same name and the old file name will be add as an Index to it.
"maxBackupIndex" is used to configure maximum number of files to be backup.
"layout" is used to set the format of the log file.
"Append" is used to set append function. If it is set to false, than every time a new file will be created rather than old file will be used for logging
How log4j is used within script?
In code, we have used "log" as a reference variable referencing getLogger method of Logger Class

Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");

Use "log" referencing variable and debug method to log the information we want.

log.debug("--information--");

What is a LogExpert tool?
LogExpert tool is a tool for Windows developed to tail the logs
It is free and open source log viewer.
It is a log analysis tool with multiple features like searching, filtering, bookmarking and highlighting the logs
In this tool logs, files get automatically updated when opened
In this tool, we can open multiple log file in different tabs
We can also put comments on bookmarks, and there is the shortcut key to navigate in between different bookmarks. We can also see complete bookmark list and navigate from there
Shortcuts of the tool are given in help file so that they can be referred to the tool.
Steps to use Log4j with Selenium
Step 1) In Eclipse create a new project with name log4j_demo

Log4j with Selenium Tutorial

Step 2) Right click on src -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Log4j with Selenium Tutorial

Step 2) Click on Libraries and Add Log4J Library . You can download it from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html

Log4j with Selenium Tutorial

Step 3) Create a new file. This file will include all the log4j configuration

Right click on src -> New -> Other -> General -> File
Give the file name as "log4j.properties"
Click on Finish
Create two more files and give them names such as Selenium.logs and Manual.logs. These files will contain all the logs created by system and manually logged statements

Log4j with Selenium Tutorial

Step 4) In log4j.properties copy the entire configuration.

Log4j with Selenium Tutorial

Step 5) Create main class:

Right click on default package -> New -> Class
Give the class name and click on finish
Log4j with Selenium Tutorial

Step 6) Copy the following code in to the main class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggingDemo {
    /**
        * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");

         driver.get("http://healthunify.com/bmicalculator/");
         log.debug("opening webiste");
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         log.debug("entring weight");
         driver.findElement(By.name("wg")).sendKeys("87");
         log.debug("selecting kilograms");
         driver.findElement(By.name("opt1")).sendKeys("kilograms");
         log.debug("selecting height in feet");
         driver.findElement(By.name("opt2")).sendKeys("5");
         log.debug("selecting height in inchs");
         driver.findElement(By.name("opt3")).sendKeys("10");
         log.debug("Clicking on calculate");
         driver.findElement(By.name("cc")).click();

         log.debug("Getting SIUnit value");
         String SIUnit = driver.findElement(By.name("si")).getAttribute("value");
         log.debug("Getting USUnit value");
         String USUnit = driver.findElement(By.name("us")).getAttribute("value");
         log.debug("Getting UKUnit value");
         String UKUnit = driver.findElement(By.name("uk")).getAttribute("value");
         log.debug("Getting overall description");
         String note = driver.findElement(By.name("desc")).getAttribute("value");

         System.out.println("SIUnit = " + SIUnit);
         System.out.println("USUnit = " + USUnit);
         System.out.println("UKUnit = " + UKUnit);
         System.out.println("note = " + note); 
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

In the above code, we visit http://healthunify.com/bmicalculator/and verify BMI calculator. The weight entered is 87KG and the height is 5 Feet 10 inches. The script checks output in SE, US and UK units.